# Install MongoDB driver for PHP to XAMPP on a PowerPC Mac

Tags: php, mongodb

I know you cannot install the MongoDB server on a PowerPC Mac, but I can't find any instructions on installing JUST the PHP driver to XAMPP.

Does anyone know if this is possible. If so, how do you do it? I've done extensive searching and can't find an answer to this.

Comment: Have you [tried the instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx) for installing on OS X?  These mention XAMPP as well. There are also [downloads available](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads) for older versions of the PHP driver that should include PPC support on php 5.2/5.3 (they appear to be universal binaries).  Would recommend trying to install the latest version from source instead.

Comment: Also FYI, looks like XAMPP hasn't been updated since 2010; [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/releases.html) seems to have some newer universal binaries.  May not make a difference for your use case, but possibly a few more PHP bug fixes included :).

Comment: I followed the instructions. I put the mongo.so in my extensions folder (with all the other extensions), and put extension=mongo.so in my php.ini file. It still does not work. :(

Comment: Did you download a compiled mongo.so, or build your own ?  If using a precompiled one make sure you have the right version to match your PHP (eg. 5.2 mongo.so for PHP 5.2?) **and** also restart your web server.  You should be able to see mongo.so in the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` output.

Comment: I have downloaded a pre-compiled mongo.so for PHP 5.3. I put it in my PHP extensions folder (/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/). I added a "extension=mongo.so" to my php.ini file and restarted the Apache server. Looked at phpinfo(), still no Mongo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I dusted off a G4 Powerbook with OS X 10.5.8 to test. Turns out that the current [precompiled version](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads) of mongo.so for PHP 5.3 on github doesn't support PowerPC (the PHP 5.2 build appears to).

I downloaded the [PHP 5.3.1 source](http://php.net/releases/index.php) to match XAMPP 1.7.3 and compiled my own mongo.so (1.2.12).

I did some minimal testing with XAMPP 1.7.3 on PowerPC to confirm this appears to work.  Essentially, I just pasted the example from the [MongoDB PHP Driver Tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php), and inserted some documents into MongoDB 2.0.6 running on another computer.

Note this is an *unofficial & unsupported* mongo.so build, the same as what you should get building successfully from source with `pecl install mongo`. As a bonus, this is a much newer driver version than the precompiled OS X ones currently on github.

As a warning: I'm not sure about limitations or quirks of using this on PowerPC.  Most of the OS X world has moved on to Intel architecture now.

So, instructions to use:

1. Download and install [XAMPP Mac OS X 1.7.3 universal binary](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html#849).
2. Download `mongo-ppc-1.2.12.so` from my github: [mongodb-php-driver/downloads](https://github.com/stennie/mongo-php-driver/downloads)
3. Rename that to `mongo.so` and copy into `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`
4. Edit XAMPP/etc/php.ini and add a last line with:

   ```
   extension=mongo.so
   ```
5. Check via phpinfo() that the `mongo` extension is available.  Make sure you stop/start Apache if it was already running when you added the extension.

Comment: I'm stuck with a PowerPC Mac, so I was getting worried the drivers wouldn't work at all. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes! It works! I can't award the bounty for another 7 hours, but this answer is totally worth it.

Comment: @Jakxr: Thanks .. great that you can still put your PowerPC Mac to good use ;-).  If the PHP driver wasn't workable for some reason, I was going to suggest using a [RESTful interface](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface) instead.

Comment: Driver works great. Sorry I can't give you the reputation, a mod closed the question.

Comment: @Jaxkr: odd that the question was closed as `off-topic` .. getting a MongoDB driver working doesn't seem unrelated to programming :).  Also curious what happens with your bounty (maybe you get it refunded?).  I'll try posting a question on meta.so.

Comment: Yeah. It's weird. And the bounty was refunded. Thanks for posting on meta.

Comment: @Jaxkr: Here's the [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144143/interpretation-of-off-topic-question-installing-a-mongodb-driver) link.  At least you got your bounty refunded ;-).

Comment: Reopened based on the meta post, I misunderstood the scope of this question when closing it. @Jaxkr you can place the bounty again if you'd like to reward this answer.

Comment: +1 for nice explanation, it looks like you are specially work in `mongo`

Comment: What about PHP7

Comment: @MáximaAlekz This question is more than five years old and was about installing on a Mac with PowerPC architecture. I'd suggest posting a new question with details of your environment (specific PHP version, O/S version, XAMPP version, and any steps you've taken or error messages encountered).

Comment: It doesn't matter. I was just asking. Talking about the same: PHP and MongoDB, the only diff is PHP version.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz I expect you wouldn't have similar issues with current versions of software. I would first try [installing the latest MongoDB PHP driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setup.php) and post a new question if you encounter difficulties. I doubt the only difference in your environment is PHP7 -- are you also running PowerPC on Mac OS with XAMPP 1.7.3, the mongo-1.2.12 legacy PHP driver, and MongoDB 2.0.6 server? All of the software versions have changed significantly in the last 5+ years.